# How to identify the POST command that the repsonse belongs to

Tags: ios, objective-c, http

I am working on an iOS application that communicates with a web server via HTTP.

In my MVC, the server communication is handled by a singleton class named serverCommunicator. There are multiple other classes that will use the serverCommunicator to send HTTP commands to the web server. The serverCommunictor sends the commands to the server then uses NSNotificationCenter to notify the listener classes when the response comes back.

My question is since each of these classes will be sending a different post command and in most cases expecting a specific post response from the server, what is the standard and correct approach to have these classes parse the response in order to figure out if this response is really for the command sent by the class.

I am new to http protocol, so I am not sure if I am doing this correctly. If there is a better way please let me know. One way I can think of is having the server add the command in the response body, but I am not sure if this is the right way to do it.

Thanks!

Comment: I would recommend you use blocks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I do is attach an identifier to the NSURLRequest. The same request comes back to you as part of the response, so you can pull out the identifier and examine it.

The means to do this is provided in rather an odd way:

```
NSMutableURLRequest* req = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[NSURLProtocol setProperty:someValue forKey:@"someKey" inRequest:req];
```

Now continue configuring the URL request as desired, and use it to make the post. When the reply comes back, pull out the request and use it the same way in reverse:

```
id value = [NSURLProtocol propertyForKey:@"someKey" inRequest:req];
```

Comment: It is odd.  I think @Azat has a better idea to use blocks, say via NSURLConnection.  Short of that, NSNotification has oft-overlooked object or userInfo properties.

Comment: I am not sure how blocks will help in my case. I want to keep all server communications in the specific serverCommunicator class. I think the answer by matt is what I was looking for. Thanks!!

Comment: Well, actually when I do it the identifier _is_ a block. The caller hands me a block, I store it in the request, then later I take it out of the request and call it - thus calling the caller back. However, that's just a special case of the general point that I'm making.